# Count and Plot String Column in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with a 'SEX' column, with Male and Female, I would like to know how to count the strings and plot this column in a bar chart in matplotlib.. thanks

Comment: What have you actually tried on your end? Could you provide the code you're working with? You write that you have a dataframe, could you provide the structure of the relevant parts of the dataframe? We're not a code-writing service here, we're here to help explain/solve errors/issues with programming.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'SEX': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female']})
df.SEX.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```